# Big Regex Stuck in. Can not match multi line parenthesis

Tags: regex, express

```
TYPE FruitEnum = ENUMERATION OF
    (APPLE
    ,BANANA
    ,PEACH);
END_TYPE;
```

I am stuck in regex problem. I want to match 'FruitEnum' and 'APPLE,BANANA,PEACH' but I can not get it. It is multi line and I couldn't find a pattern to match words. Can anyone help me about this match.

Comment: Can you show the regex you're currently using (and the code you're using to apply the regex)?

Answer (score 0):

This regex matches your example, with two groups, the first one would match `FruitEnum` and the other will match `APPLE
    ,BANANA
    ,PEACH` you only have to split the second group by `,` and trim the results to get `APPLE`, `BANANA`, `PEACH` separated:

```
/TYPE\s+(\w+)\s*=\s*ENUMERATION\s*OF\n\s*\(\s*((?:(?:\w+)(?:\s*,)?)*)\s*\)\s*;\s*END_TYPE;/gm
```

Here is a [demo link](http://regex101.com/r/sA3sK9/1)

Comment: Thank you so much. You are really superb.